# как передать данные из класса в класс python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
with open('charc.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
dic = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(dic)


class Finder(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, data_dic):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.dic = data_dic
        self.nb_name = ' '
        self.ui.find.clicked.connect(self.dataGet)

    def dataGet(self):
        name = self.dic.get(self.ui.kodtv.text(), 0)
        print(name)
        self.nb_name, self.proc, self.oper = name
        print(self.nb_name, self.proc, self.oper)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def openSecondWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def data_send(self): # этот метод должен получать и выводить данные из класса finder метода dataGet()
        print()
        # self.ui.nbname.setText(nb_name)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.  НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте `Finder()` вместо `self`

```
Finder().nb_name, Finder().proc, Finder().oper
```

Обязательно нужно перед этим инициализировать функцию dataGet дабы переменные были созданы

Comment: Eugene, ваш ответ не понятный.

Comment: бля че дурак что ль)